# Is top simplicial cohomology generator just class of dual cochain to any simplex of maximal dimension?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have a 1-dimensional simplicial complex $K$. Specifically, it is boundary of a pentagon (let's label its vertices with $1,2,3,4,5$). I want to find generator of $H^1(K)$.

What I did: I just took generator in $H_1(K)$, that is, class of the chain $c=\{1,2\}+\{2,3\}+\{3,4\}+\{4,5\}+\{5,1\}$ and took the cochain that takes value $1$ on $c$ and value $0$ on any other chain. As I understand, it must be generator in $H^1(K)$.

However, in one book I saw that generator of $H^1(K)$ is just class of cochain that takes value $1$ on any 1-dimensional simplex $\sigma\in K$.

Is it true? If yes, what is wrong with my approach?

Thank you.

Comment: Both are correct (at least with coefficients in a ring where $5$ is invertible). The cohomology class is not uniquely represented by a cocycle.

Comment: To start with, your "cochain" isn't a cochain - it isn't a linear map on chains.

Comment: Yes, are you sure you meant "value $0$ on any other chain"?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I meant this, but Jonathan explained me my ignorance. What would fix my "cochain"? I saw this strategy of taking dual cochain in order to get generator of $H^1$ from generator of $H_1$ a couple of times, but never found an explanation

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip "The cohomology class is not uniquely represented by a cocycle". What did you mean? So these two cocycles (well, if we fix the first one somehow to make it a legit cocycle) will represent the same element in cohomology? Or the will represent two different classes, but both are generators?

Comment: To define a co-chain: Pick a basis of the chain complex, and you can assign arbitrary values to each basis element. By the definitions of "linearity" and "basis" this determines a unique co-chain (and any co-chain can be gotten by this method).

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this stuff, so could you add details specifying what you mean by "dual co-chain to a simplex"?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip: So is it true for co-homology with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients? Because $5$ isn't invertible there. And I think it's a bit confusing to say something is true for (co-)homology if it fails for $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC $n$-th chain group $C_n(K)$ consists of all simplices of dimension $n$ (that is what you meant by basis of chain complex, right?). By dual cochain to $n$-dimensional simplex $\sigma$ I mean $n$-dimensional cochain that takes value $1$ on $\sigma$ and $0$ on every other simplex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the book is correct. Pick one $1$-simplex, say $c_1 = \{1,2\}$ in your example, and define a co-chain $c^1$ with $c^1(c_1) = 1$ and $0$ on the other $1$-simplexes. Then $[c^1]$ generates $H^1$.

I'll mention that the language you used, "cochain that takes value 1 on any 1-dimensional simplex $\sigma \in K$", was a bit confusing, as it sounded like it would assign $1$ to any $1$-simplex, which is wrong. You have to choose one $1$-simplex and then do the construction above, where all the other $1$-simplexes are assigned $0$. What's interesting is that no matter which $1$-simplex you choose you generate the same class in $H^1$, i.e. the co-chains differ by a co-boundary (assuming $K$ is connected).

Your construction (assuming you formalized it a bit better) really does not describe the same thing. I guess you could define $c^1(\sigma_i) = 1/5$ for all five $1$-simplexes $\sigma_1, ... ,\sigma_5$, and that would evaluate to $1$ on your generator of $H_1$, but it's messy and sometimes your coefficient ring doesn't contain 1/5.

To get a bit hand-wavey I seems like you're trying to take the thinking of $H_1$ as made up of paths and drag that over to $H^1$. If I can offer an alternate image, I had a prof who said that if chains are made up of paths then co-chains are sets of gates that sit across the paths, and evaluating a co-chain on a chain corresponds to counting up how many times your chain went through each gate and adding up the tolls. With this view we can see that to "do" $H^1$ all we have to do is put 1 gate across any of the $1$-simplexes in our complex, and we will be able to catch any generator of $H_1$ -- a path in $H_1$ will have to go through our gate because it is a "closed loop". We can also see that it doesn't matter where we put our gate -- a "closed loop" will still have to go through it.

If you want to get some experience with this thinking here's a suggested exercise: Let $a^1$ be the co-chain defined like the very beginning of this answer, i.e. dual to $\{1,2\}$ in your notation, and let $b^1$ be a similar co-chain, but dual to $\{2,3\}$. We know that $[a^1] = [b^1]$, so  $a^1$ and $b^1$ differ by a co-boundary. Find the $0$-cochain $c^0$ such that $b^1 = a^1 + dc^0$. (Recall that a $0$-cochain is basically just an assignment of a number to each vertex.) Try to see how adding the co-boundary corresponds to "shifting the gate from being across $\{1,2\}$ to being across $\{2,3\}$".

Comment: Thanks!! Yeah, only now I saw that I really did use language poorly.

Concerning the exercise: We would like $dc^0$ to be function that is $-1$ where $a^1$ is $+1$ and $+1$ where $b^1$ is $+1$, so perhaps we should take $c^0$ such that $c^0(\{i\})=1$ for $i=2$ and $c^0(\{i\})=0$ for $i=1,3,4,5$, i.e. "dual to simplex $\{2\}$".

To be honest, I still don't quite get why cochain dual to simplex is a generator. Also I am not sure about tolls' analogy, especially about "catching generators". I mean, if $K$ is disjoint union of 2 segments, I'd put gates on each of them, but $H^1=0$.

Comment: But really, is there a way to prove that cochain $\alpha$ dual to $\{1,2\}$ is a generator? I tried to do it by definition (trying to present any cochain as $n\alpha$  and it seems hard.

Comment: Ok, I proved that it is a generator by definition, but still don't really get how you could be sure that it is...